# DotNet allocates a lot of memory when querying mongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, memory, valgrind

My application is using a lot of memory because I am querying my database a lot. I am posting my C# code hoping someone can tell me what am I doing wrong. I have also created the same program using Google Go language in order to compare memory usage. The same program on C# uses over 1 GB of memory and Go only uses 100MB. C# creates thousands of allocations on the heap and Go only a few. Lastly C# took 3 seconds to compile on release mode and Go only milliseconds.

### C# code:

```cs
var mongoDb = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017").GetDatabase("MyTestDb");

var collection = mongoDb.GetCollection<Account>("Accounts");

// find all items on collection named Accounts
var items = collection.Find("{}").ToEnumerable();

int counter = 0;
foreach (var a in items)
    counter++;
Console.WriteLine(ctr2);


// I am naming my properties incorrectly just to make the code shorter and avoid having a converter
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Account
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string dateCreated{ get; set; }
    public string dateDeleted{ get; set; }
    public string dateUpdated{ get; set; }
    public string idCloudServicePbxFailover{ get; set; }
    public string idCloudServiceWebApp{ get; set; }
    public bool hasGrantedSupportAccess{ get; set; }
}
```

If I run this code with a profiler like `valgrind` I get this result:

```
==132531== HEAP SUMMARY:
==132531==     in use at exit: 96,284,945 bytes in 14,388 blocks
==132531==   total heap usage: 105,120 allocs, 90,732 frees, 177,448,116 bytes allocated
==132531== 
==132531== LEAK SUMMARY:
==132531==    definitely lost: 200 bytes in 8 blocks
==132531==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==132531==      possibly lost: 42,416 bytes in 145 blocks
==132531==    still reachable: 96,242,329 bytes in 14,235 blocks
==132531==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==132531==                         stdstring          : 41,313 bytes in 52 blocks
==132531==                         newarray           : 48 bytes in 1 blocks
==132531==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==132531== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

If I use the `time` command from Linux I get this result:

```
./bin/Release/net6.0/MyTestApp   7.48s  user 0.88s system 71% cpu 11.645 total
avg shared (code):         0 KB
avg unshared (data/stack): 0 KB
total (sum):               0 KB
max memory:                1867 MB
page faults from disk:     1
other page faults:         470073
```

Lastly if I run `htop` on Linux I see that my memory goes up more than 1 GB.

I cannot change my `Account` class to a `struct` because Mongo does not support structs. I was hoping to make this change in order to reduce memory allocations.

Anyways if I run the same program that does the same thing with Go from Google this are the results:

### Go code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    // "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    // "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/mongocryp"
)

type Account struct {
    ID                        string `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    DateCreated               string `json:"dateCreated,omitempty" bson:"dateCreated,omitempty"`
    DateDeleted               string `json:"dateDeleted,omitempty" bson:"dateDeleted,omitempty"`
    DateUpdated               string `json:"dateUpdated,omitempty" bson:"dateUpdated,omitempty"`
    IdCloudServicePbxFailover string `json:"idCloudServicePbxFailover,omitempty" bson:"idCloudServicePbxFailover,omitempty"`
    IdCloudServiceWebApp      string `json:"idCloudServiceWebApp,omitempty" bson:"idCloudServiceWebApp,omitempty"`
    CompanyName               string `json:"CompanyName,omitempty" bson:"CompanyName,omitempty"`
    HasGrantedSupportAccess   bool   `json:"hasGrantedSupportAccess,omitempty" bson:"hasGrantedSupportAccess,omitempty"`
}

var client *mongo.Client

const conString = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
const dbName = "MyTestDb"
const colName = "Accounts"

var collection *mongo.Collection

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Testing mongo")
    clientOption := options.Client().ApplyURI(conString)

    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), clientOption)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("MongoDB connected")

    if client == nil {
        fmt.Println("foooo")
    }

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)

    // cursor, err := client.Database(dbName).Collection(colName).Find(ctx, bson.D{{"dateCreated", bson.D{{"$gt", "2020"}}}})
    cursor, err := client.Database(dbName).Collection(colName).Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer cursor.Close(ctx)

    ctr := 0
    for cursor.Next(ctx) {

        ctr++
        var acc Account
        cursor.Decode(&acc)
        // if acc.ID == "96e0a7f6-5b6d-4a10-9b3d-c5d8275fdb1f" {
        //  break
        // }
    }

    fmt.Println(ctr)
}
```

This is `valgrim` output:

```
==135050== HEAP SUMMARY:
==135050==     in use at exit: 2,016 bytes in 7 blocks
==135050==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 8 frees, 2,240 bytes allocated
==135050== 
==135050== LEAK SUMMARY:
==135050==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==135050==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==135050==      possibly lost: 2,016 bytes in 7 blocks
==135050==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==135050==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==135050== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

and here is the output of `time ./mongodb-go`:

```
./mongodb-go   4.99s  user 0.44s system 72% cpu 7.463 total
avg shared (code):         0 KB
avg unshared (data/stack): 0 KB
total (sum):               0 KB
max memory:                100 MB
page faults from disk:     0
other page faults:         21916
```

Comment: solution: use GO !! :)

Comment: "C# took 3 seconds to compile on release mode" — 3 seconds to _compile_ or to _execute_?  Compilation time doesn't seem relevant here.  Also, I removed the [tag:Go] tag because it seems that code is working satisfactory to establish a baseline for memory usage and I'm not sure what users of that language would add here; it's knowledge of [tag:MongoDB] as it pertains to [tag:C#]/[tag:.NET-Core] that seems most needed.

Comment: 2 seconds actually to compile. But go took 43 ms that is impressive. And yes I agree this is not a go question. I also do not care about peformance. I do not mind if my clients take a little longer to receive the data. I just do not want my server using so much memory.

Comment: you're probably transfering many thousands of records through the wire and creating many thousands of objects in .net to hold those records with that find query without a filter or a limit. in a real world application, you won't see that being done as that many records/objects is useless for a user interface. instead you'd be running aggregations on mongo server and just displaying summarized data to the user. for example, in [this benchmark](https://mongodb-entities.com/wiki/Performance-Benchmarks.html#find-100-entities) mongo driver takes up ~450kb and takes 1ms to download 100 entities.

Comment: @MitchWheat it [doesn't look like GO is faster than .Net](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=test&runid=9a0eb3a0-f8ba-41d1-8ca9-56884c5f9e41&hw=ph&test=json&l=zijxtp-sf&c=8&a=2) at least for Web Api development ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that would be the case at all. Was just commenting on what the OP wrote.  :)  Benchmarks are notoriously hard to get right and measure like for like.

Comment: Yes I agree that benchmark are hard to get right. But just by looking at my htop command from Linux I can easily see how my whole computer memory usages spikes a lot.